# An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.(only on server)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

my asp.net mvc app working on localhost & IIS also its only problem on server ...
my problem is like Hardik Patel in this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1740103.aspx that not resolved after 3 years ...

Comment: It's almost certainly not the same problem.

Comment: i got when my actionResult method seperated to two part and use it with two request my code run correctly .... ,is it possible Due to the limited stack memory in shared host? , Another way is to resolve this problem? @JohnSaunders

Comment: my problem occured because my file on host in my app return invalid string that with encoding i can resolve it ...
but i don't know why it's work on my pc correctly . @JohnSaunders